# Wrong syntax error comming when trying to use java to insert into Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have an assignment submission in half an hour, I am desperate for help. Thanks in advance for all the support .

my code is

```
 String query= "INSERT INTO `chemistry`(Question, Answer, A:, B:, C:, D:) VALUES ('"+jTextField_Question.getText()+"' , '"+jTextField_Answer.getText()+"' , '"+jTextField_A.getText()+"' , '"+jTextField_B.getText()+"', '"+jTextField_C.getText()+"', '"+jTextField_D.getText()+"')" ;
```

Erro coming is :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':, B:, C:, D:) VALUES ('ertyjk' , '' , '' , '', '', )' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you really have columns "A:","B:", etc in your table? I'd try to get rid of the ':'

Comment: Show us your table structure please.

Comment: Thanks Eran for the help , now it's working.
Thank you .

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Comment: You should use prepared statements https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html  should help pretect you against SQL injection attacks.